# Change of chapter's head-title within that chapter (memoir)

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir

I'm struggling with chapter's title in header. Memoir gives this nice possibility of defining separate title for showing on top of the page but in some cases one would like to change it before new chapter.

Is there any way to change chapter's head-title while being still in that chapter? 
For example with the beginning of new sectioning lever or even without any, just between lines?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter*[First]{First}
\section*{SomeTextEnglish}
\blindtext[10]@english
\section*{SomeTextLatin} %form here I'd like to write in header e.g. 'PRIMUM'
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide us something to work with (in the form of a minimal example that replicates the current behaviour) and we can work some magic!

Comment: Right! I wasn't sure how to make MWE from my original code. Hope this will do :)

Comment: If your document is intended for a printed book, rather than math or an academic work or an ebook, and if you are just beginning, then have a look at the `novel` document class package. The feature you request is built-in, using commands `\SetVersoHeadText{}` and `\SetRectoHeadText{}`. Not in memoir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example a simple `\markboth` will do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter*[First]{First}
\section*{SomeTextEnglish}
\lipsum[1-10]

\markboth{PRIMUM}{}
\section*{SomeTextLatin} %form here I'd like to write in header e.g. 'PRIMUM'
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! How could I not find earlier? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Worth pointing out that `\markboth` partially ignores style of header titles. In this case 'PRIMUM' has to be written in uppercase, otherwise it'll be in small letters. Unlike title given in `\chapter` arguments, where text fully goes through header's formatting.

Comment: That's the normal behaviour for `\markboth`. You can use `\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Primum}}{}` or for memoir `\markboth{\memUChead{Primum}}{}`, which then automatically adheres to `\uppercaseheads` and `\nouppercaseheads`.